# Binomially distributed

Tags: probability

Could anyone tell me if my answer to this question is correct please? If not where i have gone wrong.

10% of components outside range. 10 components sampled, whats the probability of having 3 components that are outside the range?

$ n =$ Number of trials, $ x =$ Number of successes, $ p = 90\% = 0.9$, $ q = 10\% = 0.1$

Formula
\begin{align} p(x) &= \frac {n}{x}  p^x q^n-x\\
P(7) &= {10 \choose 3} (0.9)^7 (0.1)^3  \\
&=120 (0.9)^7 (0.1)^3 \\
&= 0.057395628\end{align}

Comment: $ p(x) = \frac {n}{x}  p^x q^n-x \ $ should be $\  p(x) = \binom{n}{x}  p^x q^{n-x} \ $. Else everything is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from dirty or incorrect notation and/or typos, your answer is correct.

Recognize, the binomial coefficient is notated with `\binom{n}{x}` and appears as $\binom{n}{x}$ and has a very different meaning than $\frac{n}{x}$

Also recognize, the term `q^{n-x}` which appears as $q^{n-x}$ where the subtraction occurs within the exponent is different than $(q^n)-x$ where the subtraction occurs outside of the exponent which is how people might have interpreted `q^n-x`.

For more typesetting tips and examples, visit the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: On this should the 3 on the second line of the equation be a 7? I am learning and think it could be wrong?

Comment: @KyleAnderson your question is whether it should have been $\binom{10}{3}$ or $\binom{10}{7}$?  They are equal.  In general $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.  You can see this algebraically since multiplication is commutative so $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-(n-k))!}$, or you can see it by a combinatorial argument like "to choose which $k$ things are 'good' and letting the others be 'bad' out of $n$ objects is equivalent to choosing which $n-k$ things are 'bad' and letting the others be 'good'"